# Characterisation of measurability for $\mathbb{R}\cup\{\pm\infty\}$-valued functions

Tags: measure-theory, measurable-functions

Let $(X,\mu,\mathcal{A})$ be a measure space. $f\colon X\to \mathbb{R}$ is $\mu$-measurable if $f$ is a $\mu$-a.e. limit of simple functions $f_j\colon X\to\mathbb{R}$. Functions $f\colon X\to\bar{\mathbb{R}}$, however, are said to be $\mu$-measurable if $f^{-1}(\pm\infty),f^{-1}(O)\in\mathcal{A}$ for all $O$ open in $\mathbb{R}$.

I know the definitions coincide if we consider $f\colon X\to \mathbb{R}$ to be a function with values in $\bar{\mathbb{R}}$. But, if we speak about convergence in $\bar{\mathbb{R}}$, is the pointwise limit $f\colon X\to \bar{\mathbb{R}}$ of a sequence of simple functions $f_j\colon X\to\mathbb{R}$ not necessarily $\mu$-measurable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pointwise limit you mention is indeed $\mu$-measurable.

More generally, if $f_n:X\to\bar{\mathbb R}$ is $\mu$-measurable for $n=1,2,\dots$ and a set $A\in\mathcal A$ exists with $\mu(A)=0$ and: $$x\in A^{\complement}\implies \lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)\text{ exists in }\bar{\mathbb R}$$ then any function $f:X\to\bar{\mathbb R}$ that equals this limit on $A^{\complement}$ is $\mu$-measurable.

It is not needed here that the $f_n$ are simple and/or take values in $\mathbb R$.

Comment: The converse also holds. If $f : X\to\overline{\mathbb R}$ is measurable, then there exists a sequence $(f_n)$ of simple functions such that $f_n\to f$ $\mu$-a.e. @drhab: What is a $\mu$-measurable function?

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp If $\mathcal A$ is a $\sigma$-algebra and $\mu$ is a measure on it then it induces $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal A_{\mu}$ with $\mathcal A\subseteq\mathcal A_{\mu}$. This $\mathcal A_{\mu}$ is the completion wrt $\mu$. I.e. if $B\subseteq A\in\mathcal A$ and $\mu(A)=0$ then $B\in\mathcal A_{\mu}$. A function is $\mu$-measurable if it is measurable wrt $\mathcal A_{\mu}$.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. So, it might happen that the limit $f$ is not $\mathcal A$-measurable, but only $\mathcal A_\mu$-measurable?

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp That can happen since we are talking about a limit "$\mu$-a.e." If $f$ is a limit on whole space of $\mathcal A$-measurable functions then $f$ is $\mathcal A$ measurable also.

Comment: Ok... But then you'd have the same issue with bounded functions, right?

Comment: Hi @drhab, I really hope that you can help me resolve my confusion in this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3523294/how-are-the-definitions-of-mathcall-0x-mu-overline-mathbbr-and). Thank you so much for your help!