# How are the definitions of $\mathcal{L}_{0}(X, \mu, \overline{\mathbb{R}})$ and $\mathcal{L}_{0}(X, \mu, E)$ consistent with each other?

Tags: measure-theory, proof-explanation, banach-spaces, measurable-functions

To remove the ambiguities, I include related definitions from my textbook $\textbf{Analysis III}$ by Amann.

---

Let $(X, \mathcal{A}, \mu)$ be a complete, $\sigma$-finite measure space and $(E,|\cdot|)$ a Banach space.

1. We say $f \in E^{X}$ is $\mu$-simple if $f(X)$ is finite, $f^{-1}(e) \in \mathcal{A}$ for every $e \in E,$ and $\mu\left(f^{-1}(E \backslash\{0\})\right)<\infty .$ We denote by $\mathcal{S}(X, \mu, E)$ the set of all $\mu$-simple functions.
2. A function $f \in E^{X}$ is said to be $\mu$-measurable if there is a sequence $\left(f_{j}\right)$ in $\mathcal{S}(X, \mu, E)$ such that $f_{j} \rightarrow f$ $\mu$-almost everywhere. We set $$\mathcal{L}_{0}(X, \mu, E):=\left\{f \in E^{X} \mid f \text { is } \mu \text {-measurable}\right\}$$
3. A function $f \in E^{X}$ is said to be $\mathcal{A}$-measurable if the inverse images of open sets of $E$ under $f$ are measurable, that is, if $f^{-1}\left(\mathcal{T}_{E}\right) \subset \mathcal{A}$, where $\mathcal{T}_{E}$ is the norm topology on $E$. If there is a $\mu$-null set $N$ such that $f\left(N^{c}\right)$ is separable, we say $f$ is $\mu$-almost separable valued.

> $\textbf{Theorem}$ A function in $E^{X}$ is $\mu$-measurable if and only if it is $\mathcal{A}$-measurable and $\mu$-almost separable valued.
>
> $\textbf{Corollary}$ Suppose $E$ is separable and $f \in E^{X}$. The following statements are equivalent:
>
> - $f$ is $\mu$-measurable.
> - $f$ is $\mathcal{A}$-measurable.
> - $f^{-1}(\mathcal{S}) \subset \mathcal{A}$ for some $\mathcal{S} \subset \mathcal{P}(E)$ such that $\mathcal{A}_{\sigma}(\mathcal{S})=\mathcal{B}(E)$.
> - $f^{-1}(\mathcal{S}) \subset \mathcal{A}$ for any $\mathcal{S} \subset \mathcal{P}(E)$ such that $\mathcal{A}_{\sigma}(\mathcal{S})=\mathcal{B}(E)$.

In the theory of integration, it is useful to consider not only real-valued functions but also maps into the extended number line $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$. Such maps are called $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$-valued functions.

5. An $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$-valued function $f: X \rightarrow \overline{\mathbb{R}}$ is said to be $\mu$-measurable if $\mathcal{A}$ contains $f^{-1}(-\infty), f^{-1}(\infty)$, and $f^{-1}(O)$ for every open subset $O$ of $\mathbb{R}$. We denote the set of all $\mu$-measurable $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$-valued functions on $X$ by $\mathcal{L}_{0}(X, \mu, \overline{\mathbb{R}})$.

---

**My question:**

From (5), the authors meant $f \in \mathcal{L}_{0}(X, \mu, \overline{\mathbb{R}})$ $\iff$ $f$ is $\mathcal{A}$-measurable. In this way, the definition of $\mathcal{L}_{0}(X, \mu, \overline{\mathbb{R}})$ requires weaker condition than the general one of $\mathcal{L}_{0}(X, \mu, E)$.

I would like to ask if the definitions of $\mathcal{L}_{0}(X, \mu, \overline{\mathbb{R}})$ and $\mathcal{L}_{0}(X, \mu, E)$ are consistent. Clearly, if $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ is separable, then they are consistent by the **Corollary**.

**Update:** @drab asserted in his [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2516578/characterisation-of-measurability-for-mathbbr-cup-pm-infty-valued-funct?noredirect=1&lq=1) that $f \in \mathcal{L}_{0}(X, \mu, \overline{\mathbb{R}}) \iff f$ is $\mathcal{A}$-measurable, but he didn't give reasoning.

Here is the screenshot from my textbook:

> [image]
> [image]
> [image]

Comment: $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ is not a Banach space, so, as far as I can tell, they're simply talking about different things, no?

Comment: Hi @Thorgott, the authors first define $\mathcal{L}_{0}(X, \mu, E)$ in general. Then they define specifically $\mathcal{L}_{0}(X, \mu, \overline{\mathbb{R}})$. I would like to ask if the definition of the specific $\mathcal{L}_{0}(X, \mu, \overline{\mathbb{R}})$ is consistent with $\mathcal{L}_{0}(X, \mu, E)$. The information I quoted is verbatim from the textbook and self-contained.[...]

Comment: [...]@drab asserted in his [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2516578/characterisation-of-measurability-for-mathbbr-cup-pm-infty-valued-funct?noredirect=1&lq=1) that $f \in \mathcal{L}_{0}(X, \mu, \overline{\mathbb{R}}) \iff f$ is $\mathcal{A}$-measurable.

Comment: My point was that they defined $\mathcal{L}_0(X,\mu,E)$ for Banach spaces $E$. The space $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ isn't a Banach space, so this is simply a different definition. I don't know the book you are using, but the definition in terms of preimages is the standard way of defining measurable functions and the Theorem you quote asserts that this coincides with the alternative definition for Banach spaces. It is true (but a different matter) that a function with codomain $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ is measurable iff it is the limit of simple functions.

Comment: Note that the notion of simplicity in my comment and the answer by drab you quote is different from the one in your book. It does not require being non-zero only on a set of finite measure. I suspect this is done to get a closer analogy between $\mathcal{L}_0$ and $\mathcal{L}_p$-spaces, but I can't tell for sure as I don't have the book.

Comment: Hi @Thorgott, could you please check if I understand your ideas correctly? In the authors' definition, $f \in \mathcal{L}_{0}(X, \mu, \overline{\mathbb{R}})$ $\iff f$ is $\mathcal{A}$-measurable. Because $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ is a separable topological space, $f \in \mathcal{L}_{0}(X, \mu, \overline{\mathbb{R}})$ $\iff f$ is $\mu$-measurable by the **Corollary**. As such, the authors' specific definition for $\mathcal{L}_{0}(X, \mu, \overline{\mathbb{R}})$ coincides with the general one for Banach spaces. Could you please explain what's *but a different matter*?

Comment: The Corollary you quote is about Banach spaces $E$. Again, $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ is not a Banach space. I called the result discussed in drab's answer a different matter, because from what I understand, it is not what your question is asking about.

Comment: @Thorgott, I now understand that we can not use the Corollary because $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ is a Banach space. The authors' definition is $f \in \mathcal{L}_{0}(X, \mu, \overline{\mathbb{R}}) \iff f$ is $\mathcal{A}$-measurable. We can prove that $f \in \mathcal{L}_{0}(X, \mu, \overline{\mathbb{R}}) \iff f$ is $\mu$-measurable with auxiliary result other than the Corollary. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Are you sure you copied 5. directly by the way? It makes little sense to call something $\mu$-measurable when the definition has nothing to do with $\mu$. As for your question, the definition 3. you gave is only for Banach spaces $E$, but in case you desire to extend it to arbitrary topological spaces, it is indeed equivalent to 5. in the case of $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ with its usual topology.

Comment: Thank you @Thorgott ! I added screenshots to my question. Please have a look at them. Maybe because in the definition of $\mathcal{L}_{0}(X, \mu, \overline{\mathbb{R}})$, there is "$\mu$-almost everywhere".

Comment: @Thorgott I'm sorry for taking your time, but I still don't understand why *the result discussed in drab's answer a different matter* than mine. It seems to me that the OP of that question uses the same definitions as mine. I think he studied it from the same textbook as mine.

Comment: I called it a different matter, because it is not what your question is about. At least to me, your question asks about the consistency of definitions of measurability and not about the equivalence of being measurable and being a limit of simple functions.

Comment: Oh my bad wording @Thorgott :( Ultimately, I would like to ask if the following statement is correct: a function $f\colon X\to\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ such that $f^{-1}(\pm\infty),f^{-1}(O)\in\mathcal{A}$ for all $O$ open in $\mathbb{R}$ If And Only If $f$ is a $\mu$-a.e. limit of a sequence of simple functions $f_j: X\to\mathbb{R}$. My question is exactly the same as the OP's.

Comment: It is correct. In fact, you can drop the $\mu$-a.e. (and you don't need any reference to a measure at all).

Comment: Thank you so much @Thorgott! Deep in my heart, I'm really grateful to your patience with me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From @copper.hat's hints and my textbook, I've figured out a proof. I posted it as an answer here to peacefully close this question.

---

Let $(X, \mathcal{A}, \mu)$ be a complete, $\sigma$-finite measure space and $(E,|\cdot|)$ a Banach space.

- We say $f \in E^{X}$ is $\boldsymbol{\mu}\textbf{-simple}$ if $f(X)$ is finite, $f^{-1}(e) \in \mathcal{A}$ for every $e \in E,$ and $\mu\left(f^{-1}(E \backslash\{0\})\right)<\infty$.
- Suppose $f_n, f \in E^{X}$ for $n \in \mathbb{N} .$ Then $(f_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ converges to $f$ $\boldsymbol{\mu}\textbf{-almost everywhere}$ if and only if there is a $\mu$-null set $N$ such that $f_{n}(x) \rightarrow f(x)$ for all $x \in N^{c}$.
- In the theory of integration, it is useful to consider not only real-valued functions but also maps into the extended number line $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$. Such maps are called $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$-valued functions.
- An $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$-valued function $f: X \rightarrow \overline{\mathbb{R}}$ is said to be $\boldsymbol{\mu}\textbf{-measurable}$ if $\mathcal{A}$ contains $f^{-1}(-\infty), f^{-1}(\infty)$, and $f^{-1}(O)$ for every open subset $O$ of $\mathbb{R}$.

> **Theorem** $f: X \to \overline{\mathbb{R}}$ is $\mu$-measurable if and only if there is a sequence of $\mu$-simple functions $f_n: X \to \mathbb R$ such that $f_n \to f$ $\mu$-almost everywhere.

---

$\textbf{My attempt}$

$\Longrightarrow$

**(i)** We consider first the case $\mu(X)<\infty$. Let $(a_k)_{k \in \mathbb N}$ be an enumeration of $\mathbb Q$ and $A_{k,n} = f^{-1} [ \mathbb B (a_k, 1/(n+1))]$. Let $A_{+} = f^{-1}(+\infty)$ and $A_{-} = f^{-1}(-\infty)$. Then $\{A_{k,n},A_{+},A_{-}\} \subseteq \mathcal A$ for all $(k,n) \in \mathbb N^2$. The continuity of $\mu$ from above and the assumption $\mu(X)<\infty$ implies there are $m_n$ and $B_n \in \mathcal A$ such that $$B^c_n =A_+ \cup A_- \cup \bigcup_{k=0}^{m_n}  A_{k,n} \quad \text{and} \quad \mu(B_n) < \frac{1}{2^{n+1}}$$

Now define $\varphi_{n} \in {\mathbb R}^{X}$ by $$\varphi_{n}(x) = \begin{cases}
{a_{0}} & {\text {if} \quad x \in A_{0,n}} \\
{a_{k}} & {\text {if} \quad x \in A_{k, n} \setminus \bigcup_{p=0}^{k-1} A_{p, n} \quad \text {for} \quad 1 \le p \leq m_{n}} \\
n & {\text {if}} \quad x \in A_{+} \\
-n & {\text {if}} \quad x \in A_{-} \\
{0} & {\text {otherwise}}
\end{cases}$$

Clearly, $\varphi_{n}$ is $\mu$-simple and $\|\varphi_{n}(x) - f(x)\| < 1/(n+1)$ for all $x \in B_n^c$. Define a decreasing sequence $(C_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ by $C_n = \bigcup_{p=0}^{\infty} B_{n+p}$. Then $C_n^c \subseteq B_n^c$ and $\mu(C_n) \le \sum_{p=0}^\infty \mu(B_{n+p}) < 1/2^n$. It therefore follows from the continuity of $\mu$ from above that $C = \bigcap_{n=0}^\infty C_{n}$ is $\mu$-null. We now set $$\psi_{n}(x) = \begin{cases} {\varphi_{n}(x)} & {\text {if} \quad x \in C_{n}^{c}} \\ n & {\text {if}} \quad x \in A_{+} \\
-n & {\text {if}} \quad x \in A_{-} \\
{0} & {\text {otherwise}}\end{cases}$$

Clearly, $\psi_{n}$ is $\mu$-simple. For $x \in C^c$, there exists $n \in \mathbb N$ such that $x \in C_n^c$. Then $x \in C_{n+p}^c$ for all $p \in \mathbb N$. So $\|\psi_{n+p}(x) - f(x)\| =\|\varphi_{n+p}(x) - f(x)\|  < 1/(n+p+1)$ for all $p \in \mathbb N$. Hence $\psi_{n} (x) \to f(x)$ for all $x \in A_+ \cup A_- \cup C^c$.

**(ii)** We next consider the case $\mu(X)=\infty$. Because $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite, there is a sequence $(A_k)_{k \in \mathbb N}$ of pairwise disjoint subsets in $\mathcal{A}$ such that $\bigcup_{k=0}^\infty A_{k}=X$ and $\mu (A_{k}) < \infty$. As in (i), for each $A_k$, there is a sequence $(\psi^k_{n})_{n \in \mathbb N}$ of $\mu$-simple functions and a $\mu$-null set $C_k$ such that $\psi^k_{n} (x) \to f(x)$ for all $x \in A_k \setminus C_k$. Moreover, $C=\bigcup_{k=0}^\infty C_{k}$ is $\mu$-null. We define a sequence $(\psi_{n})_{n \in \mathbb N}$ by $$\psi_{n}(x) = \begin{cases} {\psi^k_{n}(x)} & {\text {if} \quad x \in \bigcup_{k=0}^n  A_{k}} \\ {0} & {\text {otherwise}}\end{cases}$$

Clearly, $(\psi_{n})_{n \in \mathbb N}$ is a sequence of $\mu$-simple functions such that $\psi_{n} (x) \to f(x)$ for all $x \in \bigcap_{k=0}^\infty C_k^c$.

$\Longleftarrow$

Assume there exist a sequence $(\psi_{n})_{n \in \mathbb N}$ of $\mu$-simple functions and a $\mu$-null set $N$ such that $\psi_{n} (x) \to f(x)$ for all $x \in N^c$.

Let $O$ be open in $\mathbb R$. We define a sequence $(O_k)_{k \in \mathbb N^*}$ by $O_{k} = \{y \in O \mid d(y, O^{c})>1 / k \}$. Then $O_{k}$ is open and $\overline{O}_{k} \subseteq O$. Let $x \in N^{c}$. We have $x \in O \iff \exists k \in \mathbb{N}^{*}: x \in O_k$. Therefore, $f(x) \in O$ if and only if there exists $(k,m_k) \in \mathbb{N}^{*} \times \mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall n \ge m_k: \varphi_{n}(x) \in O_{k}$. Consequently, $x \in f^{-1}(O)$ if and only if there exists $(k,m_k) \in \mathbb{N}^{*} \times \mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall n \ge m_k: x \in \varphi^{-1}_{n}(O_{k})$. As a result, $$f^{-1}(O) \cap N^{c} = \left ( \bigcup_{(k,m_k) \in \mathbb{N}^{*} \times \mathbb{N}} \bigcap_{n \ge m_k} \varphi_{n}^{-1} (O_{k}) \right ) \cap N^{c} = \bigcup_{(k,m_k) \in \mathbb{N}^{*} \times \mathbb{N}} \bigcap_{n \ge m_k}  \left ( \varphi_{n}^{-1} (O_{k})  \cap N^{c}\right )$$

Because $\varphi_{n}$ is $\mu$-simple, $\varphi_{n}^{-1}(O_{k}) \in \mathcal{A}$ for all $(n,k) \in \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}^{*}$. Hence $f^{-1}(O) \cap N^{c} \in \mathcal{A}$. Furthermore, the completeness of $\mu$ implies $f^{-1}(O) \cap N$ is a $\mu$-null set. Altogether, we obtain $$f^{-1}(O)=\left(f^{-1}(O) \cap N\right) \cup\left(f^{-1}(O) \cap N^{c}\right) \in \mathcal{A}$$

Let $x \in N^c$. We have $f(x) = +\infty \iff \forall M \in \mathbb N, \exists N \in \mathbb N,\forall n \ge N: \varphi_n(x) \ge M$. Consequently, $x \in f^{-1}(+\infty) \iff \forall M \in \mathbb N, \exists N \in \mathbb N,\forall n \ge N: x \in \varphi^{-1}_n ([M, \infty))$. As a result, $$\begin{aligned} f^{-1}(+\infty) \cap N^c &= \left( \bigcap_{M=0}^\infty \bigcup_{N=0}^\infty \bigcap_{n=N}^\infty \varphi^{-1}_n ([M, \infty)) \right)  \cap N^c \\ &=  \bigcap_{M=0}^\infty \bigcup_{N=0}^\infty \bigcap_{n=N}^\infty \left( \varphi^{-1}_n ([M, \infty))  \cap N^c \right)  \end{aligned}$$

Because $\varphi_{n}$ is $\mu$-simple, $\varphi_{n}^{-1}([M, \infty)) \in \mathcal{A}$ for all $(n,M) \in \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$. Hence $f^{-1}(+\infty) \cap N^{c} \in \mathcal{A}$. Furthermore, the completeness of $\mu$ implies $f^{-1}(+\infty) \cap N$ is a $\mu$-null set. Altogether, we obtain $$f^{-1}(+\infty)=\left(f^{-1}(+\infty) \cap N\right) \cup\left(f^{-1}(+\infty) \cap N^{c}\right) \in \mathcal{A}$$

With similar reasoning, we have $f^{-1}(-\infty) \in \mathcal{A}$.