# Is it correct that $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ is a separable (topological space)?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, real-numbers

To remove the ambiguities, I include related definitions from my textbook $\textbf{Analysis III}$ by Amann.

---

Let $(X, \mathcal{A}, \mu)$ be a complete, $\sigma$-finite measure space and $(E,|\cdot|)$ a Banach space.

1. We say $f \in E^{X}$ is $\mu$-simple if $f(X)$ is finite, $f^{-1}(e) \in \mathcal{A}$ for every $e \in E,$ and $\mu\left(f^{-1}(E \backslash\{0\})\right)<\infty .$ We denote by $\mathcal{S}(X, \mu, E)$ the set of all $\mu$-simple functions.
2. A function $f \in E^{X}$ is said to be $\mu$-measurable if there is a sequence $\left(f_{j}\right)$ in $\mathcal{S}(X, \mu, E)$ such that $f_{j} \rightarrow f$ $\mu$-almost everywhere. We set $$\mathcal{L}_{0}(X, \mu, E):=\left\{f \in E^{X} \mid f \text { is } \mu \text {-measurable}\right\}$$
3. A function $f \in E^{X}$ is said to be $\mathcal{A}$-measurable if the inverse images of open sets of $E$ under $f$ are measurable, that is, if $f^{-1}\left(\mathcal{T}_{E}\right) \subset \mathcal{A}$, where $\mathcal{T}_{E}$ is the norm topology on $E$. If there is a $\mu$-null set $N$ such that $f\left(N^{c}\right)$ is separable, we say $f$ is $\mu$-almost separable valued.

> $\textbf{Theorem}$ A function in $E^{X}$ is $\mu$-measurable if and only if it is $\mathcal{A}$-measurable and $\mu$-almost separable valued.
>
> $\textbf{Corollary}$ Suppose $E$ is separable and $f \in E^{X}$. The following statements are equivalent:
>
> - $f$ is $\mu$-measurable.
> - $f$ is $\mathcal{A}$-measurable.
> - $f^{-1}(\mathcal{S}) \subset \mathcal{A}$ for some $\mathcal{S} \subset \mathcal{P}(E)$ such that $\mathcal{A}_{\sigma}(\mathcal{S})=\mathcal{B}(E)$.
> - $f^{-1}(\mathcal{S}) \subset \mathcal{A}$ for any $\mathcal{S} \subset \mathcal{P}(E)$ such that $\mathcal{A}_{\sigma}(\mathcal{S})=\mathcal{B}(E)$.

In the theory of integration, it is useful to consider not only real-valued functions but also maps into the extended number line $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$. Such maps are called $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$-valued functions.

5. An $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$-valued function $f: X \rightarrow \overline{\mathbb{R}}$ is said to be $\mu$-measurable if $\mathcal{A}$ contains $f^{-1}(-\infty), f^{-1}(\infty)$, and $f^{-1}(O)$ for every open subset $O$ of $\mathbb{R}$. We denote the set of all $\mu$-measurable $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$-valued functions on $X$ by $\mathcal{L}_{0}(X, \mu, \overline{\mathbb{R}})$.

---

**My question:**

From (5), the authors meant $f \in \mathcal{L}_{0}(X, \mu, \overline{\mathbb{R}})$ $\iff$ $f$ is $\mathcal{A}$-measurable. In this way, the definition of $\mathcal{L}_{0}(X, \mu, \overline{\mathbb{R}})$ requires weaker condition than the general one of $\mathcal{L}_{0}(X, \mu, E)$. Clearly, if $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ is separable, then they are consistent by the **Corollary**.

As such, I would like to ask if $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ is a separable (topological space).

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Could the downvoter mention your reasoning for downvoting my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, $\overline{\mathbb R}$ is separable, since $\mathbb Q\cup\{\infty,-\infty\}$ is a countable dense subset.

Comment: Could you please have a look at another strongly related question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3523294/how-are-the-definitions-of-mathcall-0x-mu-overline-mathbbr-and)? Thank you so much!

Comment: What do you think about my answer to *this* question?

Comment: It totally resolved my confusion. I'm just waiting to upvote and mark it as accepted. There is an amount of time to wait until I can do so.

Comment: I'm sorry, but my first comment seems rude to you. Honestly, I didn't mean so. It's just I've struggled too much with this issue.

Comment: No, it did not seem rude. Concerning that other question, I have nothing to add to the first comment that you got there.

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been bogged down by that question :(